# Using WPF and EF6 I have an issue where it permanently reports the backing model does not match the context

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-6

I have this XAML at the top of my main window

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Which the designer tells me

> The model backing the context has changed since the database was created...

I have code first migrations enabled and up to date, the data access elements are in a seperate project and the query on the database through a view model etc (MVVM) is running correctly despite being the most recent migration.

Is this a designer issue or am I doing somthing wrong using this binding approach?

Comment: What are you doing in the constructor of MainWindowViewModel?  Also, realize the designer is famous for false errors, so there might not be actually anything going wrong here.

Comment: have you tried a new 'Add-Migration'? I've had problems before where it would actually create a new, empty migration, and then was happy after I applied it. Also double-check to make sure you're connecting to the DB you think you are (I've had this happen when connecting to dev when I meant to go to staging, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, @Will I think you are correct in suggesting that there is somthing wrong in the constructor.  I had a observable collection being initialised there from the database I swapped it to a command refresh on load and the problem goes away and everything works fine.

Comment: Add that as a solution below and you can close this out.  If you look, you can find different ways to determine if you're in a designer and not perform any init work. IIRC, DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()) is a common one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused in this case by an observable collection being populated from the database inside the constructor of a view model.  In this instance I fixed it by moving it to a command to populate the list when the control was loaded.

Other approaches include 'DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()' as mention by @Will above.

In this case I stuck with populating it outside the constructor as this allowed me to use a TAP approach.